# Make an image appear only in a determinate hour and disappear after 48 hours

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to do some sort of promotion and I tried to make an image appear only at a certain time and disappear after 48 hours. I am using JavaScript and jquery to write the functions, but it doesn't work.

I created variables for Countdown and tried to use an `if` statement which should activate the image when the remaining time becomes `=< 0`.

```
<body>
<h1>Test Page</h1>

<p id="cron"></p>

<h2>Test</h2>


<div>
    <img src="Promo.jpg" id="Promox" align="middle">
    <br/>

</div>

<script>
    var countDownPromo = new Date("Aug 24, 2020, 24:00:00").getTime();

    var x = setInterval(function(){

        var now = new Date().getTime();
        var distance = countDownPromo - now;

        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

        document.getElementById("cron").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " + 
        minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

        if (distance <= 0) {
            clearInterval(x);
            document.getElementById("cron").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
        }

        if (distance <= 0){
            document.getElementBySrc("Promox").innerHTML = "Promo.jpg"
        }

    }, 1000);

</script>
```

Comment: Please provide your HTML as well

Comment: You declare a variable as `countDownPromo` but then refer to it as `countPromo`

Comment: All of your inequality operators are backwards — should be `<=` and not `=<`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems here:

- Your `src` attribute is set in html, so the image is going to show before it's supposed to
- Your code to show and hide the image will trigger at the same time
- You're trying to grab the image using a `getElementBySrc` function which isn't actually a real thing
- You're trying to show the image by using innerHTML, which could work if you changed how you were using it, but it's much easier to just set the `src` instead.

I've made some edits that I think will fix these issues.

```html
<h1>Test Page</h1>

<p id="cron"></p>

<h2>Test</h2>


<div>
    <img src="" id="Promox" align="middle">
    <br/>

</div>

<script>
    var countDownPromo = new Date("Aug 24, 2020, 24:00:00").getTime();
    var promoEnd = countDownPromo + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 48;

    var x = setInterval(function(){

        var now = new Date().getTime();
        var distance = countDownPromo - now;
        var endDistance = promoEnd - now;

        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

        document.getElementById("cron").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " + 
        minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

        if (endDistance <= 0) {
          clearInterval(x);
          document.getElementById("cron").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
        }
        if (distance <= 0){
          document.getElementById("Promox").src = "https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/forks_and_spoons.png";
        }

    }, 1000);

</script>
```